# When should I break similar data out into separate tables?

Tags: database-design, database-schema

I'm re-working the schema for my company's database that holds data about various investment products, we track mutual funds, commingled funds, separate accounts, etc. Currently, It's structured like this:

```
id | name      | class_code
-----------------------
1  | large cap | m
2  | small cap | c
```

It's extremely cumbersome to work with because there are tons of other tables that relate to it which store statistical information about the products, and to query that info you need to know a ton of special cases (I have written many 400+ line queries), and on top of it there are no referential key constraints so the data is constantly needing to be scrubbed.

I was thinking of making a bunch of smaller tables - one for each investment type, so I'd have a mutual_funds table, commingled_funds table, etc. The issue is that there are then further classifications within those categories. There are fixed income and equity type mutual funds, each of which has different types of characteristics that we store and balanced funds which have characteristics from both fixed income and private equity.

I'm wondering if I should make a table for each product type with a column denoting whether it's fixed income or equity like so

```
mutual_funds
id | name          | type
-----------------------
1  | large cap     | fixed
2  | small cap     | equity
3  | balanced core | balanced

comingled_funds
id | name      | type
-----------------------
1  | large cap | fixed
2  | small cap | equity
```

or break that down even further into tables like so:

- equity_mutual_funds
- fixed_income_mutual_funds
- balanced_mutual_funds
- equity_commingled_funds
- fixed_income_commingled_funds
- balanced_commingled_funds
- equity_seperate_accounts
- fixed_income_seperate_accounts

The advantage to this is I'd be able to make a foreign key on the characteristics tables that each point to the specific type of product, but the disadvantage is i'd have a ton of duplicated characteristics tables  (each equity table would have the same structure other than a "equity_mutual_fund" fk or "equity_commingled_funds" fk)

for reference the charactics tables look like this:

```
fixed_income_characteristics
product_id | z-score | median_mkt_cap
1          | 1.1412  | 14.12512
2          | 3.1241  | 511.1242

equity_characteristics
product_id | duration | quality
4          | 2.1241   | AA
5          | 1.1241   | BBB+
```

Also I can't do just do `equity_funds` and `fixed_income_funds` tables because the distinction between product types matters for other info about the products like composites and fees.

The only way I can figure out how to make a structure with referential key constraints on everything is to break everything out into separate tables, but that will mean my schema will have 10k+ tables by the time it's done, and it seems like a nightmare to maintain because if we want to start tracking a new characteristic we'd need to add a new column to hundreds of tables.

Any ideas? Or any helpful resources on where to go when I get stuck with what will probably be many more similar roadblocks?

Comment: Splitting things up leads to tedious queries when you want to work with them together. Look into supertype and subtype tables. Keep common attributes together and define subtypes when required for specific attributes or relationships.

Comment: Wow I've never heard of this design construct before, but from reading through a few tutorials it may be very useful in my redesign effort, thanks!